# ¿Por que mi aplicación Java no inicia?

Tags: java, sql, phpmyadmin

Hace un par de días cree una aplicación CRUD con Java y PhpMyAdmin, y estaba funcionando bien, pero hoy lo ejecuté y no inicia, me sale un error diciendo: Class "conexionSQl.conexionSQL" does not have a main method.

Clase para la conexión:

```
package conexionSQl;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class conexionSQL {

    Connection conectar=null;

    public Connection conexion(){


        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            conectar=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/producton3?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC","root","");

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Conexión Exitosa ");

        }catch (Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error de conexion " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return conectar;

    }

}
```

Como indico, la aplicación estaba funcionando con normalidad.
Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: pareces estar ejecutando conexionSQL en vez del main

Comment: Te falta el main, por eso marca error. La clase conexionSQL, ¿es independiente o lo hiciste todo en un solo archivo?

Comment: La clase conexión es independiente, igual al ejecutar la aplicación me sale este mensaje: Error de conexión Access denied for user "root"@"localhost"(using password: NO)